# Length of cycle

Tags: number-theory

What is the length of the cycle of 1/71?

Im basically stuck at this part of a long question. I dont know what I am suppose to find and my text book have no examples of it.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449433/predicting-the-number-of-decimal-digits-needed-to-express-a-rational-number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** As has been pointed out, appropriate software handles the problem quickly. Finding the answer by hand can be done, though it is more painful.

We want to compute the order of $10$ modulo $71$. The candidates are the divisors of $70$.

To compute less, if you are accustomed to Legendre symbol calculations, you will quickly find that $(10/71)=1$. So $10$ is a quadratic residue of $71$, and therefore cannot have order $70$, and indeed (since $70$ is not divisible by $4$), the order of $10$ cannot be even. That leaves the possibilities $5$, $7$, and $35$. We can use a simple calculator to show that $71$ does not divide $10^5-1$ or $10^7-1$. So the order must be $35$.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

It might help you to know that this is one of the many wonderful things that [Wolfram Alpha can do for you](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1/71).  In this case, the answer is $35$, but why is that the case?

As a hint: notice that $71$ is prime, and that the period divides $70=71-1$.  This is not a coincidence.

Comment: Can help explain. Are you referring to modulus?

Comment: This result is certainly is related to modular arithmetic.  Specifically, modular arithmetic mod $p$.

Comment: Here's a question: what do remainders/residues mod $71$ have to do with long division?

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram says period is 35.  Is this what you meant to ask?

$$\frac{1}{71}=0.0\overline{14084507042253521126760563380281690}$$